# Question about $\sigma$-Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I have this definition :[image]

after that in order to prove a theorem (with $\mu \geq 0$ $\sigma$-finite $\mathcal{T}$ complete ).

they say

"Remark that $\mu$ is equivalent to a bounded measure so applying definition 21 we obtain that :

$\mathcal{T}\subset \widehat{\mathcal{T}}\subset \mathcal{T}_{\mu}=\mathcal{T}...*$

so $\widehat{\mathcal{T}}=\mathcal{T}$

I dont understand the first equality of $*$

Help me please

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inclusion is by definition -- $\widehat{\mathcal T}$ is defined as an extension of $\mathcal T$, the second follows from the remark, and the equality follows from the assumption that $\mu$ is complete with respect to $\mathcal T$.

Comment: Ah ok thank you , when i see $\cap \mathcal{T}_{\mu}$ I automatically thought that we have juste $\cap \mathcal{T}_{\mu} \subset \mathcal{T}_{\mu}$